# MySQL - Compare query results to current table data

Tags: mysql, statements

I have the following two tables:

Table1

```
|  id |  name |  job    |      start_time      |     end_time          |
| ----| ------| --------| ---------------------| ----------------------|
| 111 |  John |  Janitor|  2016-08-20 00:01:00 |       NULL            |
| 111 |  John |  Janitor|        NULL          |   2016-08-20 00:02:00 |
| 222 |  Sam  |  Valet  |  2016-08-20 00:03:00 |          NULL         |
| 222 |  Sam  |  Valet  |        NULL          |   2016-08-20 00:04:00 |
```

Table2

```
|  name |  job    |      checkin_time    |
| ------| --------| ---------------------|
|  John |  Janitor|  2016-08-20 00:01:30 |
|  Sam  |  Valet  |  2016-08-20 00:03:30 |
|  Tim  |  Cashier|  2016-09-20 00:01:00 |
```

The following query

```
SELECT id, Table2.name, Table2.job, start_time, Table2.checkin_time, end_time FROM (
SELECT id,name,job, MIN(start_time) AS start_time, MAX(end_time) AS end_time
FROM Table1
GROUP BY id
) AS results INNER JOIN Table2 ON 
  results.job = Table2.job
  AND results.name = Table2.name
  AND (Table2.checkin_time BETWEEN results.start_time AND results.end_time OR
       Table2.checkin_time >= results.start_time AND results.end_time IS NULL);
```

will display:

```
|  id |  name |  job    |      start_time      |     checkin_time    |  end_time    |       
| ----| ------| --------| ---------------------| --------------------|----------------|
| 111 |  John |  Janitor|  2016-08-20 00:01:00 | 2016-08-20 00:01:30 |2016-08-20 00:02:00 |
| 222 |  Sam  |  Valet  |  2016-08-20 00:03:00 | 2016-08-20 00:03:30 |2016-08-20 00:04:00 |
```

How do I formulate my query so that it will return the record that was not successful/found. E.g. From Table1, the record for:

```
|  Tim  |  Cashier|  2016-09-20 00:01:00 |
```

THANK YOU in advance for your help community team!

Comment: CORRECTION on the question ... it should be for Table2 reference, not Table1. E.g. How do I formulate my query so that it will return the record that was not successful/found. E.g. From Table2, the record for:

|  Tim  |  Cashier|  2016-09-20 00:01:00 |

Comment: You can edit your question with the changes mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a right join and filter only the "no matches" using nulls:

```
SELECT table2.*
FROM (
    SELECT id,name,job, MIN(start_time) AS start_time, MAX(end_time) AS end_time
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY id) AS results
RIGHT JOIN Table2 ON 
    results.job = Table2.job
    AND results.name = Table2.name
    AND (Table2.checkin_time BETWEEN results.start_time AND results.end_time OR
        Table2.checkin_time >= results.start_time AND results.end_time IS NULL)
WHERE results.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Note that RIGHT JOINs are vanishingly rare. This might be the first one I've seen this year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NOT-EXISTS clause to perform the task: here you find rows in table2 that are not in your selection result.

```
SELECT
  name, job, checkin_time
FROM
  table2
WHERE NOT EXIST (
  SELECT *
  FROM
    v
  WHERE
    v.name = table2.name)
```

Combining together:

```
Create View v AS
(SELECT id, Table2.name, Table2.job, start_time, Table2.checkin_time, end_time FROM (
SELECT id,name,job, MIN(start_time) AS start_time, MAX(end_time) AS end_time
FROM Table1
GROUP BY id
) AS results INNER JOIN Table2 ON 
  results.job = Table2.job
  AND results.name = Table2.name
  AND (Table2.checkin_time BETWEEN results.start_time AND results.end_time OR
   Table2.checkin_time >= results.start_time AND results.end_time IS NULL));

SELECT
  name, job, checkin_time
FROM
  table2
WHERE NOT EXIST (
  SELECT *
  FROM
    v
  WHERE
    v.name = table2.name)
```